# How do you form demonyms in Sumerian as well as Akkadian?

Tags: names, sumerian, akkadian

If I'm not mistaken, the Sumerians called themselves as  (saĝ-gíg-ga) and their country as  (k-en-gi(-r), how would you turn that into an adjectival form or demonym like how -n is added to America to turn it into an adjectival form denoting to the American people, culture, etc.?

Similarly, how would demonyms be formed in Akkadian?

Comment: Are you asking about Sumerian or Akkadian? The title mentions both but the question body is only about Sumerian.

Comment: I actually meant both but I forgot to write Akkadian in the body.

Comment: I don't know for sure that it's attested in Akkadian, but the nisba suffix is found in this sense throughout Semitic and Egyptian, so is likely in Akkadian. That may a good place to look for confirmation

Answer (score 3):

Sumerian has very few words that can be described as "adjectives". Someone's homeland would instead be indicated by just combining nouns: *lú adab<sup>ki</sup>* "the man from Adab". So if you wanted to talk about a whole population, you could extend this to *nam.lú.ulu₃ adab<sup>ki</sup>* "the people from Adab". This is generally written without a genitive marker, but I believe the marker should be there in the spoken language even if it's not written.

Answer (score 3):

Most Afro-Asiatic languages would indicate this with a nisba suffix (or as Huehnergard calls it, a "relative adjective"). And indeed, Akkadian has (or at one point had) that suffix too, though it usually gets absorbed into the final vowel of whatever it's attached to: *aḫ-um* "border" + *-ī* > *aḫ-ī-um* > *aḫûm* "outsider".

Thus, the most common way to form a demonym is (practically speaking) to lengthen the suffix: *Amurr-um* "Amor" > *Amurrûm* "Amorite".

Comment: should ahûm read aḫûm or is the shift to h correct?

Comment: @Tristan: It should be _aḫûm_, yes. However, since plain "h" is not normally used in Akkadian transliteration, and "ḫ" can be a tricky character to type, it's quite common to drop the underbreve.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen ah yes, I'd forgotten there was only one guttural in Akkadian. Still, the transcription should be consistent

Comment: @Tristan Yep, just a typo. Fixed.